# python logging with subprocesses: get ordered output as it appears on screen also on log file

Tags: python, logging, subprocess, stdout

I have a python script (*script1.py*) which generates sub processes as follows:

```
print 'This is the main script'
status=os.system(command)
```

Now I execute the script and redirect the stdoutput like this:

```
python script1.py > log.txt
```

The file log.txt contains first the output of the subprocess command (called using os.system) and only *after* the string *'This is the main script'*. I would expect the *opposite order*!

If I use subprocess instead of os.system the situation is still the same:

```
print 'This is the main script'
p=subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True, stdout=None, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
status=p.returncode
```

So how can I redirect the stdoutput to a file and make sure that all subprocesses write in that file in the proper order? Note that if **I do not redirect** the standard output, the order of the log messages is correct (as it appears on the screen)!

**UPDATE**

This fixes my problem (as described [here](http://algorithmicallyrandom.blogspot.ch/2009/10/python-tips-and-tricks-flushing-stdout.html)):

```
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)
```

Alternatively one can also force the printed content to be flushed:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

however, I think this is not ideal as it should be done after each print command. So I used the first approach which has also the advantage that I can examine the logs in real time, without waiting that the computation ends before writing to file the buffered output.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module. Print is not reliable for this. Example:

```
import logging
rootLogger = logging.getLogger()

proc = subprocess.Popen(["cat", "/etc/services"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
logger.INFO('This is the main script. Here\'s the program output:')
logger.INFO(out)
```

Comment: well, this would require that I change lots of print commands in different modules... which is a pain... I would prefer to get a solution which redirects stdoutput, perhaps something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425736/how-to-redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-logger-in-py?

Comment: fyi, @Eli I found this solution which better suites my situation **sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)**

Comment: @Mannaggia you're going to run into other similar problems. Print statements just aren't meant for production use. You can keep finding hacky solutions to keep them, but you'll be much happier in the long run if you switch over to logging. It'll also give you much more fine-grained control over what's logged where.

Comment: What if my subprocess is spawned from a multiprocess function? The logger does not log then...