# Logging outputs to a text file

Tags: python

can logging outputs which appear on the terminal be redirected to a text file?
I have tried

```
                z = open('/mnt/sdc1/Ryan/Marx/newfile.txt'.format(file), 'w')
                sys.stdout= sys.stderr = z
                print ('Running the Algoritm Now for case {}'.format(file))
                run_liver_mpct_algorithms(data_paths, model_paths,[0], int(data_paths['batch_size']), data_paths['task_str']))
                z.close()
```

In th file `z` This gives me only the traceback of the error and print statements ,inside of the `run_liver_mpct_algorithms` there are many logging outputs which i would also like to go in the file.

Any ideas would be helpful,Thanks !

Comment: you need `logging` library

Comment: Do you have control over `run_liver_mpct_algorithms`? If yes, see `logging` library. If not, also look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425736

Comment: Use the logging module from the stdlib and output redirections from your OS / shell...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the logging module from the standard library? Here's a simple example:

```
import logging
log_file = 'my_log_file.log'
log_fh = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
log_sh = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
log_format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
# Possible levels: DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL    
log_level = 'INFO' 
logging.basicConfig(format=log_format, level=log_level, 
    handlers=[log_sh, log_fh])
```

You create logging messages like this:

```
logging.info('This is a log message on level INFO')
logging.warning('This is a log message on level WARNING')
```

Messages will be written to the console and to the file you specified.

Comment: You could even dispense with the FileHandler and just use output redirections from the OS / shell.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers: from my understanding of the question OP wants to do both console and file output. By leaving out the relevant log handler, it's easy to choose which kind of output you want.

Comment: Don't know about Windows but on unix-type systems you can have both the console and redirection using `tee`.

Comment: So you're saying my approach is more portable? ;)

Comment: Not necessarily - we'd need some input from a Windows power user ;)