# How to capture error message in python that is not an exception?

Tags: python

I'm using a module called pywaves for interacting with waves.exchange API. The problem is sometimes when I try to place an order, it gets rejected with an error message:

`[ERROR] Order Rejected...`

The problem is how to capture this error message in my script. The code that generates the error is:

`myOrder = myAddress.sell(assetPair = PRO_WAVES, amount = 1491999999, price = proprice1, matcherFee = 700000, maxLifetime = 3600)`

The error does not throw an exception, and is not captured into `myOrder`. How do I get the data from this error into a variable so I can work with it?

Comment: this looks like a log message which does not necessarily raise the actual error, can you show the full error?

Comment: [ERROR] Order Rejected - The asset's script of 6GQkwHGyd769EghKQ6qXhAHG55JyaFjK7VGWEKSSg4Z8 returned the error: Sell price must be >= 1637850000 wavelets in Cycle # 338.



My script needs access to the error message to pull the minimum price from it.

Answer (score 3):

The error inside the library is probably written to the standard error output [`sys.stderr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html).  You could thus redirect the error output and check if the library is writing to it.  See for instance [this question on logging error output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425736/how-to-redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-logger-in-python).

Once you have a logger (or in your case a class that records and parses any errors), use it like this:

```py
import sys
_stderr = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = MyErrorCheckLogger()
try:
    myOrder = myAddress.sell(...)
finally:
    sys.stderr = _stderr
```

Of course, you can do the same thing with `sys.stdout`—the standard output channel.

---

**Edit:** Here is a full example where we catch any error messages directly printed to the standard output (`stdout`).

```py
import sys

class ErrorChecker:
    def __init__(self, output):
        self.output = output               # Save the original `stdout` (or `stderr`)
        self.buffer = ""                   # The buffer for the message printed

    def write(self, message):
        self.buffer += message             # Add any message to our buffer
        self.output.write(message)         # Print it as original intended

    def flush(self):
        self.output.flush()

def throwError(f, *args, **kwargs):
    sys.stdout = ErrorChecker(sys.stdout)  # Create a new output-stream with buffer
    try:
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)        # Execute the code that might cause an error
    finally:
        buffer = sys.stdout.buffer         # Get the output buffer
        sys.stdout = sys.stdout.output     # Restore the original 'stdout'
    if buffer.startswith("[ERROR]"):       # If the output is an error message, raise
        raise Exception(buffer)            # it as an actual exception
    return result

myOrder = throwError(myAddress.sell, assetPair = PRO_WAVES, amount = 1491999999, price = proprice1, matcherFee = 700000, maxLifetime = 3600)
```

Comment: I added this code, and the output is the same... what variable would I use to access the error message say to pull the minimum sell price from it:

[ERROR] Order Rejected - The asset's script of 6GQkwHGyd769EghKQ6qXhAHG55JyaFjK7VGWEKSSg4Z8 returned the error: Sell price must be >= 1637850000 wavelets in Cycle # 338.

Answer (score 3):

After reading through [the actual code](https://github.com/pywaves/pywaves), it [appears](https://github.com/PyWaves/PyWaves/blob/master/__init__.py#L75) that you can use `pywaves.setThrowOnError()` to cause exceptions to be raised whenever errors are logged, such as [in the situation you describe](https://github.com/PyWaves/PyWaves/blob/master/address.py#L704). However, for whatever reason that [doesn't appear to be documented](https://github.com/PyWaves/PyWaves/blob/master/README.md), so use at your own risk. You can [use the issue tracking system](https://github.com/pywaves/pywaves/issues) to communicate with the developers about this.

Comment: The documentation looks pretty sketchy. It's hard to see why there would be a `setThrowOnError` function unless it was meant as a public API. (It doesn't seem to be used internally by any other modules).