# Python logger - Redirecting STDOUT to logfile as well as any debug messages

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I'm trying to use the logging module in Python so that, when I run my program, I end up with a log file, `debug.log`, containing:

1. Every log message (logging.DEBUG, logging.WARNING etc.)
2. Every time my code prints something to STDOUT

When I run the program, I only want the debug messages to appear in the log file, not to be printed on the terminal.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14058475/1907765), here's my example code, `test.py`:

```
import logging
import sys

root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

fh = logging.FileHandler('debug.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

sh = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
sh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
sh.setFormatter(formatter)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)

root.addHandler(sh)
root.addHandler(fh)

x = 4
y = 5
logging.debug("X: %s", x)
logging.debug("Y: %s", y)
print("x is", x)
print("y is", y)
print("x * y =", x*y)
print("x^y =", x**y)
```

And here's what I would want to be the contents of `debug.log`:

```
2021-02-01 12:10:48,263 - root - DEBUG - X: 4                            
2021-02-01 12:10:48,264 - root - DEBUG - Y: 5
x is 4
y is 5
x * y = 20
x^y = 1024
```

Instead, the contents of `debug.log` is just the first two lines:

```
2021-02-01 12:10:48,263 - root - DEBUG - X: 4                            
2021-02-01 12:10:48,264 - root - DEBUG - Y: 5
```

When I run `test.py`, I get this output:

```
2021-02-01 12:17:04,201 - root - DEBUG - X: 4
2021-02-01 12:17:04,201 - root - DEBUG - Y: 5
x is 4
y is 5
x * y = 20
x^y = 1024
```

So I've actually got the opposite results to what I want: the log file excludes STDOUT prints where I want them included, and the program output includes the debug messages where I want them excluded.

How can I fix this, so that running `test.py` only outputs the lines in `print` statements, and the resulting `debug.log` file contains both the DEBUG logs and the print lines?

Comment: If you really want to use `print()` and log all `stdout` output to file, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/616645) can help. However, instead of `print()`, I would just use a `logging` logger, with a special stream handler that prints to `stdout` without any additional formatting.

Comment: And there are many similar questions, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/19425736.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can make it work, but I don't yet know whether there are any repercussions due to it.  Perhaps others will be able to point out any potential pitfalls, such as multithreading.

You can set `sys.stdout` to any file-like object that you like. This would include the file to which your `logging.FileHandler()` is writing. Try this:

```
fh = logging.FileHandler('debug.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

old_stdout = sys.stdout    # in case you want to restore later
sys.stdout = fh.stream     # the file to which fh writes
```

And you can remove the code that deals with `sh` that is hooked up to stdout.

Comment: Looks like what is proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31688396

Comment: @djvg: is it?. didn't look it up beforehand. Maybe the question should be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want ALL `stdout` output going to log file.

What you could do is set the logging level of the console handler to `logging.INFO` and the logging level of the file handler to `logging.DEBUG`. Then replace your `print` statements with calls to `logging.info`. This way only info messages and above will be output to the console.

Something like this:

```
import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
file_handler = logging.FileHandler("debug.log")
console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

console_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
file_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

console_handler.setFormatter(console_formatter)
file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)

logger.addHandler(console_handler)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) #set root logging level to DEBUG

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = 4
    y = 5
    logger.debug("X: %s", x)
    logger.debug("Y: %s", y)
    logger.info("x is {}".format(x))
    logger.info("y is {}".format(y))
    logger.info("x * y = {}".format(x * y))
    logger.info("x^y = {}".format(x ** y))
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/B1gc92C9ed)

Comment: Note that `StreamHandler()` uses `sys.stderr` by default, not `sys.stdout` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler)).

Comment: @djvg Thanks for pointing that out. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want **all** output to `stdout` to end up in the log file, see e.g. [mhawke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65993593), as well as the linked questions and answers.

However, if you are really just interested in the output from your own `print()` calls, then I would replace all of those by `Logger.log()` calls, using a custom logging level. That gives you fine-grained control over what happens.

Below, I define a custom log level with a value higher than `logging.CRITICAL`, so our console output is always printed, even if the logger's level is `CRITICAL`. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#levels).

Here's a minimal implementation, based on the OP's example:

```
import sys
import logging

# define a custom log level with a value higher than CRITICAL
CUSTOM_LEVEL = 100

# dedicated formatter that just prints the unformatted message
# (actually this is the default behavior, but we make it explicit here)
# See docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter
console_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')

# your basic console stream handler
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
console_handler.setFormatter(console_formatter)

# only use this handler for our custom level messages (highest level)
console_handler.setLevel(CUSTOM_LEVEL)

# your basic file formatter and file handler
file_formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('debug.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# use a module logger instead of the root logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# add the handlers
logger.addHandler(console_handler)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

# include messages with level DEBUG and higher
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# NOW, instead of using print(), we use logger.log() with our CUSTOM_LEVEL
x = 4
y = 5
logger.debug(f'X: {x}')
logger.debug(f'Y: {y}')
logger.log(CUSTOM_LEVEL, f'x is {x}')
logger.log(CUSTOM_LEVEL, f'y is {y}')
logger.log(CUSTOM_LEVEL, f'x * y = {x*y}')
logger.log(CUSTOM_LEVEL, f'x^y = {x**y}')
```