# How can i write cmd error in a file to check my python programm?

Tags: python, file, cmd, report, txt

I want to write a report of my python program while using cmd.
I have some few line of print command in my python program.

When I write :

```
C:/monchemin>program.py>report.txt
```

Ok, cool, I find all my print in a txt file, but I search to print the error who is write in my cmd. For example if the cmd say me :

```
variable x doesn't exist
```

I need to keep this error in the report.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Use logging module instead of print and redirect to file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect `stderr` to `stdout` with:

```
C:/monchemin>program.py>report.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks for your speed and efficient reply !

Answer (score 0):

Python's `logging` module is the best way to handle getting output to a file. This will prove MUCH more flexible and useful than RAW prints when working on bigger projects. Handling redirects from stdout and stderr can be added like in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31688396/9296093).

```
import logging, sys
class LoggerWriter:
    def __init__(self, level):
        self.level = level

    def write(self, message):
        if message != '\n':
            self.level(message)

    def flush(self):
        pass

log = logging.basicConfig(level = logging.WARN, filename="log.txt")


logging.error("This will be logged") # level error > warn
logging.info("This will not be logged") # level info < warn

print("This will not be logged")
#raise TypeError("This will not be logged")

sys.stdout = LoggerWriter(logging.debug)
sys.stderr = LoggerWriter(logging.warning)

print("This will BE logged")
raise TypeError("This will BE logged")
```

As you can see, there is much greater control over what will and will not be printed to console and what will be saved into a file.

Answer (score 0):

The script execution from command line, write all the messages  into file "report.txt", you can use below mentione syntax

```
C:/monchemin>program.py 1> report.txt 2>&1
```

- The standard output is directed to the "report.txt" file identified
  by output number 1.
- The standard error output identified by the    number 2 is redirected
  to the output file identified by number 1.

You can also turn off either Standard Output or Standard Error by redirecting the output to a NUL instead of a file.

```
For example
C:/monchemin>program.py 1> report.txt 2>nul
```

Only redirect the Standard Output (report.txt file), but  the error won’t display inside the console also not create an error log file.

Other option is to **adds logging calls** to "program.py" code to indicate that certain events have occurred.
Events also have an importance also  called the level or severity.

- DEBUG : Detailed information, typically of interest only when
  diagnosing problems.
- INFO : Confirmation that things are working as expected.
- WARNING :An indication that something unexpected happened, or
  indicative of some problem in the near future (e.g. ‘disk space
  low’). The software is still working as expected.
- ERROR : Due to a more serious problem, the software has not been able
  to perform some function.
- CRITICAL : A serious error, indicating that the program itself may be
  unable to continue running.

script : program.py (add import logging module)

```
import logging

# The basic configuration for the logging system by creating a StreamHandler with a default Formatter and adding it to the root logger.
#  If you run the above script several times, the messages from successive runs are appended to the file ==> default filemode='a'
logging.basicConfig(filename='report.txt', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)

# If you want each run to start afresh, not remembering the messages from earlier runs, you can specify the filemode argument to filemode='w'
# logging.basicConfig(filename='report.txt', filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG)

#Logs a message with level DEBUG on the root logger (to report.txt file).
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
#Logs a message with level INFO on the root logger (to report.txt file).
logging.info('So should this')
# Logs a message with level WARNING  on the root logger (to report.txt file).
logging.warning('And this, too')
# Logs a message with level ERROR  on the root logger (to report.txt file) .
logging.error('variable x doesn't exist')
```

Link: please check https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html