# How to get all python console messages in a log file?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, fastapi

I am using a custom logger along with sys.stdout to get print statements into a log file, however, i want everthing that python outputs on console into a file.

I am using FastAPI to create a api with custome logger.
Code for logging to the file:

```
# Define a custom class to redirect print statements to a file
class PrintToFile:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def write(self, text):
        self.file.write(text)
        self.file.flush()
        sys.__stdout__.write(text)

# Open file to redirect print statements
print_file = open('api.log', 'a')
sys.stdout = PrintToFile(print_file)


# Create a custom logger
logger = logging.getLogger("api_logger")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
sys.stderr = logger
# Create a formatter with the desired format
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(ip)s - %(domain)s - %(message)s", datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# Create a file handler for the complete log
file_handler = logging.FileHandler("whatsapp_api.log")
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# Add the file handler to the custom logger
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

However, I cant understand how to get all console messages including errors and package warnings into the file.
For example:

```
elastic_transport.TlsError: TLS error caused by:TlsError(TLS error caused by: SSLError([SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:852)))
```

P.S - I don't want to use try block because the code is almost 10k lines and it will require a lot of time to add these try blocks.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70899261/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: @Chris that only gives out print statements and messages added in log not the console outputs.

Comment: You might want to have a look at how to add (global) custom exception handlers. Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800464/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804) (see Options 2 & 4), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954531/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72833284/17865804).

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6234405) might help as well.

Comment: @Chris I think i might have confused you, I want to redirect everything that python prints on console into a file.
For example, depreciation warning, errors, module not found, print statements, warnings. 
Anything that comes on console i want in a file.

Comment: `print` uses `sys.stdout` to write to stdout, so you can replace `stdout` with your custom implementation that redirects to your logging framework: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425736/how-to-redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-logger-in-python - the same with  `stderr` as shown in the example. That should hopefully catch most, as long as the errors happen after you've modified `sys`

Comment: @MatsLindh I tried all of these, however, i am getting stdout messages in file but not stderr