# Python Logging on the fly

Tags: python

What I am trying to achieve here is being able to check the logs without closing the server. So I have written my server in python and I am able to use logging in python. But I can only see the logs once I close the server. Is there any way I can see the logs as when it is updated. Like I open the log file and I can see the logs of things that have happened and the server can contiue doing its work.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How are you logging? Show us a line of code that logs something.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633911/does-python-logging-flush-every-log

Comment: Please [don't add a signature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5038/135956). Consider changing your username instead... That's what it's for. See also [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/135956) about Hi/Thanks/etc

Comment: @Blorgbeard- currently what I am doing is:  with open(FILE_NAME,"a") as logger: /* all the things to log in between */ logger.write("Server starting") . SO, when you will stop the server, log file is getting created with all the logs. But Can I open the log file anytime and see the logs. I am stuck with this. Also, I tried using logging package of python but that did not help either.