# Enabling unbuffered output in python 3.x (with wxPython GUI) logging

Tags: python, wxpython, output-buffering

I have a Py3.x GUI app I've been building with `Gooey`. The app is fully functional, and the GUI works as intended, with the exception of the built-in console/terminal receiving buffered output.

This isn't an issue if I run the `.py` file with `pythonw -u script.py`, however I'm now trying to bundle/freeze the tool in to a `.app`. The bundling process has worked, but there is still the issue of buffered output when the app is opened.

So far, I have found the following, but nothing I've tried has worked:

- Several threads have suggested using `flush=True` with `print()` to write on each call, but `logging` - which is what I'm interested in here - has no such complementary flag. Consequently, the various monkey-patching solutions in that thread are also no use to me (with the caveat that I don't know the internals of `logging` well, so perhaps there is a similar approach applied to a logger that could work? `Gooey` itself, and the packaging process outputs much more logging info than my own calls, and that is still buffered, so it seems that 'global unbuffering' is what's really needed anyway.
- [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering) offers a number of approaches. Indeed, re-opening `sys.stdout` with a 0 buffer size is the [suggested approach](https://chriskiehl.com/article/packaging-gooey-with-pyinstaller), however there is conflicting opinion in the first thread about whether it still works on Python 3 in light of PIP 3116, and certainly in my hands, use of

  ```
  nonbuffered_stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)
  sys.stdout = nonbuffered_stdout
  ```

  seems to break the `.app` altogether.
- Trying to 'inject' a `-u` or `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` into the shebangs also does not seem to work (in this case on MacOS), with or without `-S`.

---

#### So, **TL;DR**:

#### How can unbuffered output be achieved in Python 3.x, when the script is not being explicity invoked with `python3 -u` ?

I'm still trying to put together a MWE, but the use of `gooey` combined with the packaging process is making this a bit difficult.

Comment: On which OS are you?

Comment: Sorry yep, should have said. This is on OSX 10.14. Python via conda in PyCharm. I’ll get module versions and things when I’m back at my computer.

Comment: This is weird... According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633911/does-python-logging-flush-every-log, logging flushes all output immediately by default.

Comment: is this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071448/redirecting-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-pyqt4-qtextedit-from-a-secondary-thread anyhow close to your problem ? Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881696/unbuffered-stdout-in-python-as-in-python-u-from-within-the-program ?

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering help? Especially the 4th option.

Comment: @OrdoFlammae I’m afraid not. As I mentioned in the OP, setting the buffer to 0 is no longer supported in Py3. I will explore the `Unbuffered()` class suggested in the first answer though thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering)