# Python logging - How to flush with every write to log file?

Tags: python, logging

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633911/does-python-logging-flush-every-log) implies that Python logs are flushed with every write.

My experience with Python 3.8.1 on Windows 10 is that there is some buffering happening.

I have implemented very simple logging based on the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#basic-logging-tutorial)

```
import logging
<snip - other setup>
logging.basicConfig(filename='MyLog.txt', level=logging.DEBUG)

while True:
    <snip - get the data>
    if newdata == 1 :    
        print ("> ",DataString,sep='')
        logging.info(datettime_string+' '+DataString)
```

New data appears once every several minutes, which prints and logs one line of text.
As I watch the console output, and compare that to the logging file, I see a significant delay (several data updates) before the log file is updated.
Is there a way I can set the logging file to unbuffered, or explicitly flush the log file?

Comment: The other question clearly shows that it flushes the Python stream. If it's not working, it seems like an OS problem.

Comment: How are you checking the log file, maybe the problem is there.

Comment: I'm using Notepad++ to monitor the log file. It has a mechanism (File Stats Auto-detection) to reload changed files. It does re-load changed file immediately when the application gains focus.

Comment: I suspect the issue is with the 'if newdata ==1'.  I've confirmed your setup otherwise.  I'm running under Windows 10, using Notepad++.

Comment: @Jeremy -  The `print ("> ",DataString,sep='')` statement is working and printing the data at the exact moment it is available. Only the `logging.info` is delayed.  If the `newdata==1` was not working, then the `print` statement would not be executed either.