# Python grpc server not working properly in docker container

Tags: python, node.js, docker, grpc

I am having an issue running a python grpc server in a docker container, where my server is up and running but there are no logs showing up.

This is what my proto file looks like

```
syntax = "proto3";

// The health check service definition.
service HealthCheckService {
  rpc HealthCheck (HealthCheckRequest) returns (HealthCheckResponse) {}
}

// The request message containing the client's name.
message HealthCheckRequest {
  string client_name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the return message
message HealthCheckResponse {
  string message = 1;
}
```

Python server `Server.py`:

```
import grpc
from concurrent import futures

from generated.health_check_service_pb2 import HealthCheckRequest, HealthCheckResponse
import generated.health_check_service_pb2_grpc as health_check_service_grpc

class HealthCheckServicer(health_check_service_grpc.HealthCheckService):
    def HealthCheck(self, request: HealthCheckRequest, context):
        return HealthCheckResponse(message="Hello, %s!" % request.client_name)

def serve_grpc():
    port = "50051"
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    health_check_service_grpc.add_HealthCheckServiceServicer_to_server(HealthCheckServicer(), server)
    server.add_insecure_port("[::]:" + port)
    server.start()
    print("GRPC Server started, listening on port " + port)
    server.wait_for_termination()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve_grpc()
```

NodeJS client, `client.js`:

```
var parseArgs = require('minimist');
var messages = require('./generated/health_check_service_pb');
var services = require('./generated/health_check_service_grpc_pb');

var grpc = require('@grpc/grpc-js');

function main() {
  var argv = parseArgs(process.argv.slice(2), {
    string: 'target'
  });
  var target;
  if (argv.target) {
    target = argv.target;
  } else {
    target = 'localhost:50051';
  }
  var client = new services.HealthCheckServiceClient(target,
                                          grpc.credentials.createInsecure());
  var request = new messages.HealthCheckRequest();
  var user;
  if (argv._.length > 0) {
    user = argv._[0]; 
  } else {
    clientName = 'world';
  }
  request.setClientName(clientName);
  client.healthCheck(request, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("ERROR:", err);
    }
    console.log('Health Check Response:', response.getMessage());
  });
}

main();
```

To set up, I do this. Run `./gen-protos.sh` which does the following:

```
cd ../server
mkdir -p generated
rm -rf generated/*pb2.pyi
rm -rf generated/*pb2_grpc.py
rm -rf generated/*pb2.py
python -m grpc_tools.protoc --proto_path=../protos --python_out=generated --grpc_python_out=generated --pyi_out=generated ../protos/*.proto

cd ../client
mkdir -p generated
rm -rf generated/*.js
grpc_tools_node_protoc --proto_path=../protos --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:generated --grpc_out=grpc_js:generated ../protos/*.proto
```

Then I build the docker server and run it

```
docker build . -t grpc-test-server
docker run -d -p 50051:50051 grpc-test-server
```

However, there are absolutely no logs from the print statements when I do `docker container logs ..`, though I can hit the server with the node client by running `node Client.js`

Comment: did you EXPOSE 50051 in dockerfile?

Comment: Exposing 50051 should not be necessary, its just for documentation purposes. Also the server *IS* working, just for some reason there are absolutely no logs

Comment: After each tall to `print(...)`, do a `sys.stdout.flush()`.

Comment: To make it autoflush, do `sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)` before your first `print`. Other ways to solve it: https://realpython.com/python-flush-print-output/

Comment: Is this a recommended way to force auto flush logs? Or should I use a logging library?

Comment: Also, `sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)` doesn't work. Repeatedly see this error in docker logs: `ValueError: can't have unbuffered text I/O`

Comment: A better way I have discovered is using either `python -u Server.py` to auto-flush, or use `logging` module with `stream=sys.stdout`

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59812009/what-is-the-use-of-pythonunbuffered-in-docker-file

Comment: Your server has a single `print` statement that is executed at the beginning. The output is not enough to fill the buffer and so it does not flush stdout and thus nothing appears on the `docker container logs`. If you add a `print("something")` inside the `def HealthCheck` method you should see the logs at some point.

IMHO for logs use `logging` which takes care of buffering.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to set `PYTHONUNBUFFERED`  within your docker file

```
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

<Rest of your docker code>
```

Answer (score -1):

Considering [Python logging flushes every log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16633911/6309), you can try, for your `server.py`:

```py
import grpc
import logging
from concurrent import futures

from generated.health_check_service_pb2 import HealthCheckRequest, HealthCheckResponse
import generated.health_check_service_pb2_grpc as health_check_service_grpc

class HealthCheckServicer(health_check_service_grpc.HealthCheckService):
    def HealthCheck(self, request: HealthCheckRequest, context):
        logging.info(f"Received HealthCheck request from {request.client_name}")
        return HealthCheckResponse(message=f"Hello, {request.client_name}!")

def serve_grpc():
    port = "50051"
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    health_check_service_grpc.add_HealthCheckServiceServicer_to_server(HealthCheckServicer(), server)
    server.add_insecure_port(f"[::]:{port}")
    server.start()
    logging.info(f"GRPC Server started, listening on port {port}")
    server.wait_for_termination()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', handlers=[logging.StreamHandler()])
    serve_grpc()
```

You can combine that with a dedicated [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#cmd) or [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#entrypoint) using the unbuffered mode:

```
# Assuming the Dockerfile sets up the environment and copies the server script into the container
# Change the CMD or ENTRYPOINT line to include the -u flag
CMD ["python", "-u", "Server.py"]
```

---

Looking at "[What is the use of `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` in Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59812009/6309)", as suggested by [zori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21863762/zori) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78024447/python-grpc-server-not-working-properly-in-docker-container#comment137773534_78024447), in Dockerfiles, setting the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable is a common practice to achieve the same effect as running Python with the `-u` flag, but without needing to modify the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` instruction.
It makes sure all Python scripts executed within the container run in unbuffered mode by default. That would be cleaner and more scalable, especially for containers that might run multiple Python scripts or applications.

```
# Set PYTHONUNBUFFERED to make sure Python output is logged immediately, without buffering
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Rest of your Dockerfile content
```